# Call a content slot whose id is in a variable (Salesforce B2C)

Tags: b2c

I was trying to call a content stol in a template whose id is in a variable coming from controller (i.e: pdict.contentSlotID).

I can use pdict data in all template but slot id. Is there any way to do this?
Thank you.

Comment: Please [edit] to show what you tried - e.g. a relevant snippet of your template, as text (use markdown to make it a code block).

Answer (score -1):

This is not possible. The  tag only accepts static values.

This is described "unofficially" here: https://www.rhino-inquisitor.com/can-a-isslot-element-have-a-dynamic-id/

Comment: Please ensure that your answer provides more than your assertion this is how it works. E.g. quote from documentation and provide a link to that documentation (doing both in case the documentation link breaks in future).

Comment: @PhilW this is not documented in any official documentation. So I can't quote anything or link something.